# MYSQL Trending Query

Tags: mysql, sql, select, trending

I have a table called `log` that logs recently used items the columns are as follows:

- `u_id`(a unique number)
- `item_id` (an item id number)
- `access_time`(a server timestamp)

I would like to create a query that finds the trend of the most accessed items over a period of time. For example what are the top 10 items that were accessed the most in the last 60 minutes (server time).

How can I create such a query?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT item_id, COUNT(*) FROM log 
WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, access_time, NOW()) <= 60
GROUP BY item_id
ORDER BY COUNT(item_id) DESC
LIMIT 0,10
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd just count the items the items accessed in the last hour, order by the number of accesses, and take the top 10:

```
SELECT   item_id, COUNT(*)
FROM     log
WHERE    access_time >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
GROUP BY item_id
ORDER BY 2 DESC
LIMIT    10
```